# Is there any way how to teach Eclipse CDT generate code as in JDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse

is there any chance for generating C++ code in Eclipse CDT [in the way](http://www.sdilej.eu/pics/049c98b475a3b7c6ab4ffd3b7a50e3b5.png) it does with Java?
..at least constructors?